# Image Path isn't displaying image

Tags: php, mysql

Am wondering why these image isn't showing even after properly retrieving the image path from MYSQL i've gone through the code and i still can't figure out why this is:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT description, quantity, product_price, category, product_img_url";
$sql .= " FROM *****, *****";
$sql .= " WHERE product_id = product_img_id";
$sql .= " AND product_id = ?";
$sql .= " LIMIT 1";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows==1){                                            
$stmt->bind_result($desc,$qty,$pr,$cat,$product_img_url);

$stmt->fetch();

?>
<div id="infobox">
<h3>Product View</h3>
<p align="left">

<?php

if(file_exists($product_img_url)){
echo '<img src="'.$product_img_url.'" alt="" width="300" height="300" />';
}else{
echo '<img src="" alt="product image" />';
}
?>
```

Please can someone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Have you verified the value you are getting is correct? Have you verified the image exists? Is the path correct?

Comment: Do you have proper permissions for that file if it exists?

Comment: @JohnConde I verified it, with something like if(url exists) echo 'url exists!' and it echoed it! i have used a similar method to display a users's profile photo, though through a function, and it displayed quite alright! i was surprised and confused when this happened! i even echoed the url, copied it and pasted into my FileExplorer Address bar and the image was opened with GIMP - My default image viewer!

Comment: @skywalker Am sure i have the proper privilege(s), Otherwise I would have gotten an E-Notice from php!

Answer (score 0):

If the image file does exist, then this might have something to do with the path.

I would use firebug to play with the image src path and try various things like putting a slash in the beginning, or removing it, or entering absolute path of image.

Once I get the image to show up in firebug, I would then proceed to fix the issue in the code.

Comment: interesting only that I don't know if I have the firebug plugin installed on firefox. Is it installed by difficult?

Comment: The developer tools is installed by default. Just hit F12.

Answer (score 0):

As i am see you code and i just want to ask you that you have store complete path of your image in db or you have store just some part of it.

as i can see you have retrieve image path from mysql but the browser not able to retrieve image from your server path it may be because of path you r providing and and where the file store not match. the best way to check your file path and mysql path use

```
var_dump(your result set) and check you output weather image url match with your server image path, and i am prety much sure that your path will not match.
```

Comment: you are very correct! The issue is with the path. I just find it difficult with understand relative and absolute path! Any help as regards this? A Tutorial perhaps? I've read about using DOCUMENT_ROOT, but I discovered it also includes the filesystem related paths. I also know about dirname(__FILE__), it's gotten me confused to say the list.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with the following path structure

echo '<img src="/application_root_directory/'.$product_img_url.'" alt="" width="300" height="300" />';

Comment: The problem as I understand, is that <img> tags don't accept filesystem related paths! My image has something like C:/... Which is my mistake. Am just having issues with relative and absolute links, especially as I have numerous sub directories under my root directory!

Comment: you can check with first absolute path then relative path what happens

Answer (score 0):

Well, You can do like:

```
$product_img_url="guarantee.png"; ?>
<img src="images\<?php echo $product_img_url; ?>" alt="Hello">
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not installed by default you have to install it manually. Either you can do goto tools in menubar>add-ons, and search in search fox for firebug or [goto firebug website to install it.](http://getfirebug.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for all useful ideas presented, I appreciate. I've found a way to resolve the relative/absolute links. The images are now being displayed as they should! What I did was; since I have sub directories under my root folder, I created separate 'Meta' php scripts in each sub directory with names like **INC**, __ADM, etc. Each script links to another script in a toplevel directory. All I placed within the scripts were just paths, that I got using DOCUMENT_ROOT, doing this I was able to get the actual path to the image folder, that I then placed in the DB. Hope this idea helps someone else!